# After Deny Total Control the file has gone

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions

To make a test, I've marked "Deny Total Control" to a file to all groups, and the file disappeared. Now, how I undo this condition? I've already tried to enforce the directory permission to all childs. Also tried to enforce onwership to all childs.

Comment: Can you see it from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Go to security tab as an administrator, choose advanced > owner tab > take ownership and then set suitable permissions

Comment: You mean on parent folder's property? Or file's property? Because I already did that to folder, and no user can see de file, even the administrator. That's the dilemma.

Comment: The permission to list the file is on the parent folder